# How to draw bezier curve randomly for every second? also using the transition.dart

Tags: dart, bezier, stagexl

I want to know how to draw bezier curve randomly that change every second with animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very specific question. To generic answer is that each draw command on the graphics class returns an object. You can use this object to change the properties (x, y, color, width, ...) of the draw command later. This example should give you an idea:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart';

void main()  {

  var canvas = html.querySelector('#stage');
  var stage = new Stage(canvas, width: 800, height: 600);
  var renderLoop = new RenderLoop();
  renderLoop.addStage(stage);

  var shape = new Shape();
  var movetoCommand = shape.graphics.moveTo(100, 100);
  var bezierCommand = shape.graphics.bezierCurveTo(500, 200, 200, 500, 500, 500);
  var strokeCommand = shape.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Red, 15);
  stage.addChild(shape);

  stage.juggler.translation(500, 200, 5.0, Transition.sine).listen((v) {
    // change "controlX1" of the bezier draw command in an animation
    bezierCommand.controlX1 = v.toDouble();
  });

  stage.juggler.translation(200, 500, 5.0, Transition.sine).listen((v) {
    // change "controlX2" of the bezier draw command in an animation
    bezierCommand.controlX2 = v.toDouble();
  });

  stage.juggler.translation(15, 50, 15.0, Transition.sine).listen((v) {
    // change "width" of the stroke draw command in an animation
    strokeCommand.width = v.toDouble();
  });

}
```

I won't describe how to make the positions of the bezier curve random, that's just a specialized case of the example shown above.

Comment: Btw. you can learn more about the Juggler framework here:
http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=juggler

Comment: I got the idea. but how can I change it every second?

Comment: stage.juggler.interval(1.0).take(15).listen((counter) {
    print(counter); // count up to 15 every 1.0 seconds
});

Comment: Each draw command (moveTo, liveTo, curveTo, ...) will returns an object. The movetoCommand is the return value of the moveTo draw command. You could change the x and y properties of the moveTo draw command with this object.It is not used in the shown example, but i showed that the moveTo command also returns an object.

Comment: this site is what i want to make. please help. :D